# @media display-mode: fullscreen does not work on Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, media-queries

i want to add to my css
the fullscreen check, similar to this below :

```css
 @media all and (display-mode: fullscreen) {
      body {
          background-color: red;
      }
    }
```

this example has taken from here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/display-mode

I would need it to work on **Chrome mobile Android**, but as of today, I'm trying but it doesn't work, although it is compatible, on other mobile browsers(Edge or Samsung browser) it works.

Note: to launch Fullscreen on browser i use something like :

```
function fullScreenMode() {
        var doc = window.document;
        var docEl = doc.documentElement;
        var requestFullScreen = docEl.requestFullscreen();
            requestFullScreen.call(docEl);
}
```

then fullScreenMode()  via debug on Chrome:inspect on console,